# Is it possible to enable Google Drive API Uploads to show in the Google Drive UI?

Tags: ruby, google-drive-api

I am an automation tester, and the development team I am working is doing some work with Google Drive, ultimately files uploaded to a certain folder on the drive for an account will be processed and will appear in our App (a frontend UI).

I am trying to automate testing of this, and therefore need to upload files to google drive. I am using the Ruby gem google-drive-ruby. I am successfully able to authenticate and upload files via the API with the following code:

```
    @client = Google::APIClient.new(:application_name => $config[:google_drive][:app_name],
                                   :application_version => $config[:google_drive][:app_version])

    key = Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pkcs12(File.absolute_path($config[:google_drive][:keyfile]), $config[:google_drive][:passphrase])

    @client.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
        :token_credential_uri => $config[:google_drive][:token_uri],
        :audience => $config[:google_drive][:audience],
        :scope => $config[:google_drive][:scope],
        :issuer => $config[:google_drive][:issuer],
        :signing_key => key)

    @client.authorization.fetch_access_token!

    @session = GoogleDrive.login_with_oauth(@client.authorization.access_token)

    @session.upload_from_file(File.absolute_path($config[:google_drive][:text_file]), "#{filename}", :convert => false)
end
```

Now this successfully uploads files, but they do not show up in the Google Drive UI (for that google account) and I am only able to verify they exist by making API calls:

```
    i.e. @session.file_by_title("#{filename}".
```

I read here (https://developers.google.com/drive/web/appdata) that the google drive API uses a hidden location.

Is there any way for the files uploaded via the API to appear in the UI? I want to be sure that the files I upload via the API are picked up by the code written by the developers? I am assuming that if the files are hidden in the UI then they will not be picked up by the dev code.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are using a Service Account. A Service Account is **not** the same as your user account and therefore **does not** have any UI.

You can either:-

- carry on and just live with the lack of UI.
- upload to a folder within your service account which you have shared with a real user
- use a refresh token to upload to a real user account

btw your reference to appdata is a red herring.